# Ember: installing ember-bootstrap and ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

Has anyone installed both the ember-bootstrap and ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy addons before?

The ember-bootstrap addon provides components, while the ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy addon provides the css in sass format. I want the components from ember-bootstrap, but I want do have my project in sass.

I plan to disable the css/theme from ember-bootstrap, thus using the js and font files. While I plan to disable the js and font from ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy, and use the scss files (for css and theme).

I looked through the index.js files in both addons and it seems like this will work. Plus the bower dependencies both install the same versions of bootstrap 3. To me this looks ok.

Comment: What is the actual problem with your project?

Comment: @locks no problem, but since I'm new I'm wondering if this could be problematic down the line.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can't think of any problem you might have in the future if it already works, besides the usual projects not being maintained, etc.

Comment: @locks good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of `ember-bootstrap` maintainers, my opinion is biased, but I recommend you to go with [ember-bootstrap](https://ember-bootstrap.com).

It is well-maintained, feature-full and customizable.

It users Sass and can be customized with Sass variables.

The components it provides are very handy. You'll have hard time building them by hand and integrating with Bootstrap JS.

And it relies on latest version of Bootstrap 4.

[ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy) hasn't had commits for over a year and appears abandoned. It is stuck with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I did go with ember-bootstrap, thank you for your work! However, after spending well over 100hrs trying to get my project running with way to many difficultyies I abandoned Ember, started over with Express with Jade, and I was able to launch my product within 200hrs. Maybe Ember just wasn't for me.